# Neutrino-Nucleus scattering

Tags: neutrinos

For calculating the amplitude of the coherent elastic neutrino-nucleus scattering, I face the problem in finding the coupling constant for the vertex of nuclei and the Z boson.

$$ \gamma^\mu(g_V-g_A(\gamma^5))$$

[image]

In this case if we have a nucleus (A) with Z number of protons and N number of neutrons, how we can we find the value of this coupling constant for this vertex?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4915590 where the $G_F$ in formula 1 is  the fermi constant , which is good if low energies are involved.  The W and Z couple with individual protons and neutrons where the constituents quarks  are represented by parton distributions.

Answer (score 1):

This thesis (http://compphys.ugent.be/docs/theses/WauthierSamuelThierry_2016-2017.pdf) indicates that the "coupling constant" (i.e. the term attached to the spinors and momentum 4-vectors) is:

$$-\frac{G_F}{\sqrt{2}}Q_Wg_L\gamma^\mu(1-\gamma^5)F(q^2)$$

where $F(q^2)$ is the nuclear form factor. So the "coupling constant" is explicitly a function of the momentum transfer in the reaction, and not in a trivial way - nuclear form factors do not come from first principles, and must be measured in experiments.

Comment: I am very thankful for the reply, actually in the formula you mentioned, the $Q_W$ which is the weak charge, and in the paper is calculated, I did not realize how the $g_A$ is not taken into account, and only the $g_V$ from the axial-vector is taken.